# triggering jquery on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to trigger a `.show` on a div, when a link has a dynamically added class and it's parent has the class `pdSelectedSwatch`  which is added on selection(click).

example code:

```
<li class="pdSelectedSwatch">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="outOfStock">
      <img class="outOfStock" src="/outofstock.gif" > 
   </a>
</li>



if ($("a.outOfStock").parent().hasClass("pdSelectedSwatch")) {
    $(".stockMessage").show();
}
```

But I can't get it to work properly, and I'm betting my syntax is off.

I should note that the `outOfStock` class is determined by values in an xml file, and there are several functions that determine the link's class based on that file.

I should also note that the site is using jQuery 1.4.2, which won't be updated at thsi time.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can we have some of your html to make sure the selectors are right?

## reponse to user edit

```
//if the xml is parsed and used on page load, then just find the offending a.outOfStock elements
$(document).ready(){
//.find assumes the stock message is a child of the a.outOfStock Element.
// i am inferring there could be multiple a.outOfStocks on a page, and the message is localized.
 $(".pdSelectedSwatch > a.outOfStock").find(".stockMessage").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

---

```
//a global ajax complete event, you must check the uri used to be sure it is the ajax call you care about!
// you should probably add a 'complete' event to the original ajax call if you have control of it
// if you're still reading, then you may not be in control of the xml ajax call.
// you can still listen for a jQuery complete event.  this only works if the xml ajax call used jQuery as well.
$('selector for whatever called the ajax').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/uri/you/used/to/get/the.xml') {
    $(".pdSelectedSwatch > a.outOfStock").find(".stockMessage").fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
```

---

```
// as of 1.4.2
$(".pdSelectedSwatch > a").delegate(".outOfStock","click", function(event){
         $(".stockMessage").show();
        });
```

Comment: I could use what event your XML file triggers when done being processed.  is it on page load?  (I currently guessed using the 'click' event) ... sidenote, do you want to stop the 'a.outOfStock' link from firing its default href?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an incredibly complex amount of js involved around these functions. So I'm trying to avoid tapping in to them at this time, and just wanting to show a div if certain conditions are met.

Comment: good answer, and I'm giving you credit, but unfortunately I'm going to have to wade through the mass of js and find the right event because it is preventing other events