# jQuery is triggering multiple events for the content that are generated before Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have building a dynamic purpose based form fields repeater, but having some difficulties on jQuery click event function.

You can watch my [code here](http://leading-people.com/resources/form/) - http://leading-people.com/resources/form/

I want to clone the input field only once in its own parent **td** when clicked.
Which is working in this case only for the input fields that are shown already and then assigning **click event's function** for the fields which are dynamically created.

> Problem is that when I create dynamic field once, It will create a clone perfectly and the same happens with the dynamic generated input fields, but when do I press the **elder input field (which is already spawned at initial stage)** it clone multiple times.

Tried many other ways listed similar to this Question but can't get through it.
Similar Questions I found on SO but these doesn't helped me at all.

- [triggering jquery on dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402639/triggering-jquery-on-dynamic-elements)
- [Prevent click event in jQuery triggering multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012447/prevent-click-event-in-jquery-triggering-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("table").on("click","input",function(){
        var dd = new Date(),
            ddClass= dd.getDate()+"-"+dd.getSeconds();

        $(this).clone().attr("class",ddClass).appendTo($(this).parent());
    });        
});​
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CLyRc/4

In this code we use the table to listen for any click events on the inner input fields, then simply clone that clicked input and append it to the parent (in this case the `<td>` tag).

In your code, it looked like you were repeatedly adding event listeners to all input fields, whereas in my example we are using event delegation to listen for the event only one time on any input field, dynamically added or not.

Comment: This works for me amazingly. :) 
But one thing; How the "Click Event" is firing for the newly dynamic created content i.e. in this case "input" tags?

Comment: @Hammad A. It works through event delegation. Instead of attaching the event listener to each individual `<input>` tag, which we would also have to do for each dynamically added `<input>`, we add a listener to the table.

When an `<input>` field is clicked, the event propagates up through the parent elements all the way to the top of the DOM tree. As it propagates, it will pass through the `<table>` and trigger the event.

It doesn't matter if an `<input>` has been dynamically added or not.